# Meteor + jQuery Mobile + Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, meteor

How to connect jQuery Mobile (meteor add ...)? I understand that you can connect by adding the head, but I do not want to.

I know about how to use [Meteor + Phonegap](http://zeroasterisk.com/2013/08/22/meteor-phonegapcordova-roundup-fall-2013/), however, advise which option is better?

Outdated information:
[jQuery-Mobile Meteor sample integration and/or integration guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139425/jquery-mobile-meteor-sample-integration-and-or-integration-guidelines)

Comment: Guys, what negative, if there is no answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new jQuery mobile (jqm) demo app at [jqmdemo.meteor.com](http://jqmdemo.meteor.com)
because the "old" demo app (jqm.meteor.com) wasn't working as expected.

You can create a package in your local lib folder to use jqm in meteor (see source code on bitbucket, link is on the demo page).

There's no meteorite package for this at [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com//) yet (mrt add ...). I haven't created one, because I think there are still many things that can be improved in the demo (e.g. popups are not working in the demo).

Also event binding needs to be re-checked because I added the event to the rendered function of the templates with jQuery.on(...).
Attaching the jquery mobile events to the template.[yourtemplate].events({}) handler would be better, but I don't know how to do this.

I can not say anything to phonegap at the moment. Because I haven't tested it. 
But at the moment I think that jqm and meteor is a bit slow in performance. If you have a look at the fontawesome-demo inside of the jqm demo you'll notice that it takes quite long to render the >300 icons. Maybe a server side rendering would be better, but I think that's not ready in meteor.

Comment: I'm curious if you made any further progress on this and if so, do you have something you could share (github)?

Comment: No, sorry, no further progress. What are you looking for? At the moment, I'm learning Python and Kivy to do "native" Android apps. But no Kivy app to share yet. I'm just doing tutorial things like the PongGame and learning the basics of Kivy... (Kivy is a great framework to do touch apps with Python.)

Comment: Does this mean you decided to move away from jqm and meteor for some reason? I'm going to check out your stuff on bitbucket. Thx.

Comment: No, I still think that Meteor and jQm is great. But I don't have a real project at the moment and I have more ideas for mobile apps. Also loading gets faster, I've found that there's a "fast-render" mrt package. That improves loading speed. Maybe I'll add that to the demo page.